# React sub-component expander and shared state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-context

I'm wanting to create an expandable section with heading that when clicked toggles the expandable section to show/hide.

I have done this before with regular components etc, but this time I am trying to do this with sub-components and am coming a bit stuck with how to get the state working...

Should I be trying to pass the states into the sub-components directly in the main expander component, or should I be trying to use a context to share the state?

For context, I was reading [this](https://dev.to/shayanypn/buckle-with-react-sub-component-10ll) article which didn't delve into passing functions (helpful, I know).

**App.js**

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Title>Dropdown One</Dropdown.Title>
      <Dropdown.Body>Some content in the body</Dropdown.Body>
    </Dropdown>
  </div>
);
```

**useExpandDropdown.js** Custom hook

```
const useExpandDropdown = (initialState = false) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(initialState);

  const toggleExpand = () => setIsExpanded((prev) => !prev);

  return [isExpanded, toggleExpand];
};

export default useExpandDropdown;
```

**Expander.js**

```
import useExpandDropdown from "../Hooks/useExpandDropdown";
import DropdownBody from "./DropdownBody";
import DropdownTitle from "./DropdownTitle";

const Dropdown = ({ children }) => {
  const [isExpanded, toggleExpand] = useExpandDropdown();
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

Dropdown.Title = DropdownTitle;
Dropdown.Body = DropdownBody;

export default Dropdown;
```

**ExpanderTitle.js**

```
const DropdownTitle = ({ children }) => {
  // I want to access the toggleExpand function in here
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

export default DropdownTitle;
```

**ExpanderBody.js**

```
const DropdownBody = ({ isExpanded, children }) => {
  // I want to access the isExpanded state here
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

export default DropdownBody;
```

Comment: could you share an example of how you use the Expander / Dropdown component?

Comment: would you consider using a library like headless UI for this?

Comment: I'd combine the body and title into a single component to make things a lot easier

Comment: @szaman updated to show how it'll be used.

Comment: @0stone0 I agree, I'd usually do it the more reasonable way, but I'm experimenting with sub-components

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, and the right choice depends on the specifics—how your components are structured, what they look like and how you're using them.

But for most cases, I would outsource this kind of logic to a 3rd-party library so you can spend time maintaining your app instead. One choice is Headless UI and they have a component called [Disclosure](https://headlessui.com/react/disclosure) that you can use here.

```
import { Disclosure } from "@headlessui/react";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Disclosure>
      <Disclosure.Button>
        Dropdown One
      </Disclosure.Button>
      <Disclosure.Panel>
        Some content in the body
      </Disclosure.Panel>
    </Disclosure>
  </div>
);
```

As you can see, it's very simple, and depending on what exactly you're doing you might not need the `Dropdown` components at all.

---

Note that `Disclosure.Button` renders a `button` by default, which, depending on your environment, might come with some default styling you might not want. You should either style it or render something different than a `button`, e.g.:

```
<Disclosure.Button as={div}>
```

or

```
<Disclosure.Button as={DropdownTitle}>
```

Just remember to add a11y, since it's an interactive element.

Comment: and if you're trying to learn it, you could inspect the source code of a library that does this. here's headless UI, as you can see, they're wrapping a context provider around the main wrapper, and accessing the state through that: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/blob/main/packages/%40headlessui-react/src/components/disclosure/disclosure.tsx#L214

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to figure out how to do it by hand, and yes I was looking into the HeadlessUI code for how they do it. A bit more involved that I first thought, but mainly because it's typescript so a lot of waffle. As I suspected though, they are using context.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `cloneElement` to add the `props` (`isExpanded` or `toggleExpand`) to the children.

I'm using `children[0]` and `children[1]` to 'split' the `title` and `body`, this could be improved in a number of ways, like `[ title, body ] = children` if you're sure there are only 2 elements.

---

Example, press the `title` to toggle the `body`

```js
const { useState } = React;

const useExpandDropdown = (initialState = false) => {
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(initialState);
    return [isExpanded, () => setIsExpanded((prev) => !prev)];
};

const Dropdown = ({ children }) => {
    const [isExpanded, toggleExpand] = useExpandDropdown();  
    return (
        <div>
            {React.cloneElement(children[0], { toggleExpand })}
            {React.cloneElement(children[1], { isExpanded })}
        </div>
    )
};

const DropdownTitle = ({ children, toggleExpand }) => <div onClick={toggleExpand}>{children}</div>;
const DropdownBody = ({ children, isExpanded }) => <div>{'Body is: '}{isExpanded ? 'Visible' : 'Hidden'}</div>;

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <Dropdown>
            <DropdownTitle>Title</DropdownTitle>
            <DropdownBody>Some content in the body</DropdownBody>
        </Dropdown>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: that's an interesting solution! it should be noted that it's very rigid, i.e. you cannot add any other children or reorder the children, without breaking it.

Comment: Seems like OP just want a title and body, nothing else. I've added some text to explain the splitting. A spread syntax could 'solve' the issue with multiple children

Comment: Ah yes, this makes some sense. Re-reading the article I linked in the original question I see that they are doing something similar at the bottom of the article, only using a map instead to search for a custom prop they add.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using the render props pattern. In this approach, the state is managed by your main component, and passed to child components as props at render. This is a commonly used patterns in many libraries, e.g. Formik.

The advantage is complete flexibility—your API is open for extension in the future, as you can define the structure of your components without any restrictions. A disadvantage is that it's a little verbose and can result in prop drilling if you child components have several levels of nesting.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const MyDisclosureTitle = ({
  children,
  onClick,
}) => {
  const style = { all: "unset" };

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} style={style} type="button">
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

const MyDisclosureBody = ({ children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

const MyDisclosure = ({ children }) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const toggleExpanded = () => setIsExpanded((prev) => !prev);

  const disclosureBag = {
    isExpanded,
    toggleExpanded,
  };

  return children(disclosureBag);
};

MyDisclosure.Title = MyDisclosureTitle;
MyDisclosure.Body = MyDisclosureBody;

const Example = () => {
  return (
    <MyDisclosure>
      {({ isExpanded, toggleExpanded }) => (
        <div>
          <MyDisclosure.Title onClick={toggleExpanded}>
            Dropdown One
          </MyDisclosure.Title>
          {isExpanded && (
            <MyDisclosure.Body>Some content in the body</MyDisclosure.Body>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </MyDisclosure>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is a typescript example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-disclosure-example-bqrtsk